# Data won't show, search in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a problem in my datagridview. The data won't show in the datagridview. Here's my code in winforms:

```
void FillDataGridView()
{
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SearchLog", sqlCon);
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text.Trim());
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = dtbl;
    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    sqlCon.Close();
}
private void logmanager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDataGridView();
}

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FillDataGridView();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message");
    }
}
```

and here's my query in stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchLog]
@UserID nchar(10)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM User_Activity_Log
WHERE UserID LIKE @UserID+'%'
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the SQL command externally? I see you're doing LIKE X%. But note, that X% will finds any value that starts with X.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Not sure if that helps, but don't know what error you're coming across. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: So, what about the DataTable? Does it contain anything?? Use the debugger before asking here and always tell us the results..

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter are IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Also, you may want to take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: is any data comes to this line `sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);` ?

Answer (score 0):

> [you can use the Data source by this way => open the **Design** Gridviwe page and click on the small button called **GridView Tasks** and choose your Data Source by choose a **New Data Source** ]

[image: text]

> [will appear page choose **Database** and make the **ID** for the
>   **Data Source** and Choose your **Data Connection**]

[image: text]

> [And enter your **Server Name** and **enter a Database Name** ]

[image: text]

> [And Run your Gridviwe ] I hope that I could solve your problem

[image: text]